# How to automatically call a method to stop a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, race-condition, event-listener

I'm realizing a little project in which female viviparous animals can have a gestation (a class which implements Runnable).

Here's my Gestation class :

```
private final class Gestation implements Runnable //inner class of Viviparous
{                                                
        private boolean isWorking;
        private Viviparous[] babies;
        private final int time_end;
        private int time_left;
        private Enclosure e;

        public Gestation(Viviparous[] b, Enclosure e)
        {
            if(Viviparous.this instanceof Lion) 
                this.time_end = Lion.TIME_GESTATION;
            else if(Viviparous.this instanceof Gazelle) 
                this.time_end = Gazelle.TIME_GESTATION;
            else if(Viviparous.this instanceof Otter) 
                this.time_end = Otter.TIME_GESTATION;
            else
                this.time_end = 0;
            this.time_left = this.time_end;
            this.e = e;
            this.b =b;

            this.isWorking = true;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        public Viviparous[] getBabies()
        {
            return this.babies;
        }

        public boolean isWorking()
        {
            return this.isWorking;
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            if(this.time_left == 0)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().stop();
                this.isWorking = false;
                System.out.println("Gestation ended");

                Viviparous.this.calve(this.e); //calving in Enclosure e.
            }
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            while(this.isWorking)
            {
                this.time_left--;
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(400L);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if((this.time_left)%10==0 && this.time_left != 0)
                    System.out.println("Gestation will end in "+this.time_left+" days.");
            }
        }

}
```

I would like to trigger stop() when time_left == 0.
Right before I haven't had stop() method, only run() in which the loop stopped when time_left == time_end then called calve() of Viviparous.this, this last method asks the user to name the babies with an input.
The problem is that my programm already asks the user to select an option from the current menu :
I guess there's a conflict between entering babies name and menu option.

Comment: `Thread.stop()` is [unsafe and deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()). Don't call it.

Comment: I will remove it ! Threads stops anyway when they reach their end, don't they ?

Comment: They would, but your thread won't ever finish, since `isWorking` is never set to false in this thread (and can't be reliably from another thread, as it is not volatile).

Comment: All that use of `Viviparous.this` makes your code unreadable. Try to use `this` as little as possible. If the variables are in scope, just use them. And the `instanceof` thing in the constructor - just write a method `getGestationTime()` in `Viviparous` and override it in the specific animals, instead of using this unwieldy construct. Finally, take a look at `java.util.Timer` instead of trying to write a sleep loop.

Comment: Here's why I would like to trigger stop() when time_left==0.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : Viviparous is the outer class of Gestation...

Comment: I know. I gave you advice about your style, as your current one makes your code unreadable.

Comment: There's yet another problem here. You are starting the thread by letting the `this` reference escape during the construction of `Gestation`. One should avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the thread to stop automatically.

A thread stops when its run method either returns or throws an exception.  If you want the thread to stop, then make it return from `run()`.

If you want it to automatically stop when `time_left == 0`, then test `time_left` in the thread's top-level loop, and have it return when `time_left == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a volatile boolean field (eg. isWorking) and provide a method to set it. You can then stop the thread by calling that method. Make sure the variable is a volatile, otherwise it may not be noticed...

```
private volatile boolean isWorking = true;

public stopThread() {
    this.isWorking = false;
}
```

No need for deprected Thread.stop() anyways.

Comment: thanks ! but I want the thread to stop automatically. I'm looking into Observer/observable pattern.